# Connecting to MySQL(WAMP) database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, wamp, wampserver

Here is what I am trying to do.

I have an index.php page which accepts user input and then transfers it to infosubmitted.php

```
    <?php
include('header.php');
?>

<body>
<form action="infosubmitted.php" method="post" id="infosubmitted">
<div id="header">
<h1><strong>Enter In The Data</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
<table border="0" width="75%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="10%">First Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">Last Name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">Age: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="3" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="right" width="10%">City: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" />
</div>
</body>

<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Now, I am trying to get the variables and store them in a database called test in a table called people

Here is the dbconnect.php

```
<?php
// Set the database access information as constants 

define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'phpmyadmin');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

?>
```

And here is the model.php

```
<?php
// model for the totals of the wreath orders
require_once("dbconnect.php");

// connect to database and check errors
@ $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$connection_error = $dbc->connect_error;
if ($connection_error != null) {
  echo "<p>Error connectiong to database: $connection_error</p>";
  exit();
}
?>
```

Here is infosubmitted.php

```
<?php
require_once("model.php");


$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$city = $_POST['city'];

insertIntoTable($fname, $lname, $age, $city);



function insertIntoTable($fname, $lname, $age, $city){
global $dbc;

$insertRow = 'INSERT INTO people(fname, lname, age, city) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$city')';
$result = $dbc->query($insertRow);
header('location: getinformation.php');

}
?>
```

Then I want it redirected to getinformation.php to take the record back out of the database so I can store it back into variables.

```
<?php
include('model.php');
include('header.php');

$fname = $people['fname'];
$lname = $people['lname'];
$age = $people['age'];
$city = $people['city'];
$dbc->close();
?>
<div id="header">
<h1><strong>This is the information you submitted</h1></strong>
</div>
<div id="main">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>First Name:</td>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Name:</td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Age:</td>
        <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td><?php echo $city; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

I get the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\infosubmitted.php on line 17

I know I could just keep passing the variables from the index to info submitted and then to getinformation but I am trying to get a grasp on connecting to the database.

I want to have the user enter data, have the data sent to another page then that data is put into the table then redirect to a new page and have the information from the table dumped back into variables so I can put them on the screen.

Comment: all files are located in the same folder.

Comment: Before you write any more SQL code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should **never** include user data directly in your query string. Using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) is the safest way to do this correctly every time.

Comment: You seems to be very new in PHP. I advise you to learn PHP properlly before start coding.

Comment: @tadman ok I will read up on that

Comment: Like I said, this is just a test.  This isn't live.  This is for my use only.  I know about validating at server and on the page, but I just don't have validation set up in this example.  I am new fairly new to PHP, we didn't cover it extensively in the class I had.  I appreciate all the answers.

Comment: It's okay. Sorry for jumping on you like that, but bad habits like this aren't corrected immediately you will be a gigantic liability to any project you're working on. Even one slip can have enormous consequences, as a single unescaped variable could be enough to destroy the entire database, or retrieve all the data stored in it. The risks are way too high.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your statement with double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
$insertRow = "INSERT INTO people (fname, lname, age, city)
VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$city')";
```

In it's current state the your queries are unescaped and is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should consider escaping them with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or using similar methods.

The entire `ext/mysql` PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix `mysql_`, is [officially **deprecated** as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. Consider switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)

Comment: Two same answers at same time. Funny.

Comment: and after you use Amal's answer, give a little thought to securing your script. Right now its pretty weak.

Comment: New error.  Notice: Undefined variable: people in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\testwebpage\Model\getinformation.php on line 5

Comment: @jordankoal: you're doing `$fname = $people['fname'];`. You need `$fname = $_POST['fname'];`. Do that for all the similar statements.

Comment: I am still a bit new but why would I use $_POST data when I'm not getting it from anywhere but the database?  THat page is designed to open the database and get the record in the fname field of the people table.

Comment: Because $_POST, $_GET and $_REQUEST are used to get URL parameters send by the web page.

Comment: These **must** be escaped. This is reckless.

Comment: I am not trying to use parameters sent to the webpage I am trying to get records from the table?  How does the page know what table in the database to get the information from if I don't specify? or what field in that table?

Comment: I know it's not secure. I am just trying to get it work right and then I'll do other work to it.

Comment: @tadman: Updated the answer with a suggestion to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: @jordankoal The number one rule is to not write deliberately insecure code in the first place. You will make a mistake one day, forget to fix it, and the consequences can be disastrous. Like firearm safety, you **must** be disciplined about not leaving SQL injection bugs in your code. You do not know how your code will be used in the future, so you cannot *assume* that it won't be an issue.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to say that you have a quotes error in your insert code.  Use escapes, double quotes, or some other mechanism to separate the quoted variables from the quoted string, like so:

```
$insertRow = "INSERT INTO people(fname, lname, age, city) VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$city')";
```

Comment: Two same answers at same time. Funny.

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use PDO to connect database and excute the statements. You never worry about your issue because statements can be prepared before excuting.

Have a look on manual of PDO here http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

If you'd like to know which should you choose between PDO vs MySQLi. Please read the summary below:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059

Hope that help you!